# What does res.locals.path = req.path; in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I try to figure out what this code does:

```
const app = express();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.path = req.path;
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.locals` is typically used to surface variables from middleware to a template engine being used to render the page with `res.render()` in a subsequent request handler (later in the request handler chain).  You can read the doc [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals).

So, this particular middleware is making `req.path` available to the template engine (by putting that value into `res.locals.path` so that it can be used in rendering the page as just `path` (not sure what the template wants to do with the path - that's up to it).

Note that the actual route that is calling `res.render()` can pass data directly to the template engine as an argument to `res.render()`, but this can't be done by middleware because the middleware itself isn't calling `res.render()`, so its alternative is to put the data into `res.locals` where the template engine can pick it up from there.

`res.locals` starts out each request as empty so it contains nothing until your middleware or request handlers puts something in it for purposes of rendering a page for that specific request.